# Rails association confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my app I have users, teams, and tools. Users and teams share a habtm relationship. Now I want to setup the relationship of tools with the other two models such that a user is able to have different tools depending on which team he belongs to.

So a scenario which I should be able to handle is if user X belongs to team T1 then he can own tools a,b,c in this team, and if the same user belongs to team T2, then he might own a different tool set (say d,e,f) in T2. I should be able to edit the list of tools that user X owns in team T1 and  T2 individually.

I was initially thinking of doing a "users has_many tools :through teams" but am not sure if this will result in me capturing the scenario mentioned above.

Comment: Does a user 'lose' a tool if he owns a tool that is removed from his team?

Comment: yes, that would be correct, the user will lose the tool in this case.